# WPF Tab Control + Animations

Tags: wpf, animation, tabcontrol, styling

I'm trying to style/animate a TabControl such that when a tab is selected, the old one fades out, and the new one fades/slides in.  I have the tab control styled, to a point, but now I'm trying to work out how to animate the panel.  Blend doesn't seem to be much help: there are references to styling "target-element", and references to "Panel" in the xaml, but neither of these seem to work when attempting to animate properties of this element.

I'm attempting to animate the Opacity property, and the transform property.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks in advance.

XAML attached:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderTabControlItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource TabItemFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,1,6,1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabControlNormalBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeTabIn">
                        <!-- This is where I am trying to put the animation code, the following (commented) line is an example. -->
                        <!--<DoubleAnimation By="0.6" From="0.5" To="1" Storyboard.TargetName="target-element" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" /> -->
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="layoutRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Opacity="0.6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.9" ScaleY="0.9"/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="layoutRoot" Value="1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="layoutRoot" Value="0.4"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="layoutRoot" Value="0.25"/>
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="layoutRoot">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.8" ScaleY="0.8"/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FadeTabIn_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeTabIn}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, I hope someone answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the tab control is not as versatile as it could be. Your best bet in this situation is to use custom controls for each tab item, and to create handoff storyboards for fading in/out.

My trick for this is to use visual states and behaviours, and custom templated radio buttons as switchers.

Create storyboards to animate the visibility from collapsed > visible, then fade up the opacity from 0 > 100.

You can see an example of this exact technique on my blog, under the Websites section of the homepage Silverlight xap on http://www.blackspike.com

Comment: Thanks. I just ended up ditching that particular effort. Twas a shame.

Comment: I actually wanted to add subtle animations to elements all around my app too, ended up customizing them to the last bit to get satisfactory results. Doing all this in WPF sure is a bit wacky and might seem hard but if you know your way around and have the time, it sure is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectionChanging` and `SelectionChanged`, and you can apply this to multiple tabcontrols.  I am using Devexpress, but it should work with any WPF 4.0 tab control, since I am only using the `SelectionChanging` and `SelectionChanged` events.

VB:

```
Private Sub TabControl_SelectionChanging(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Xpf.Core.TabControlSelectionChangingEventArgs) Handles tcMaterials.SelectionChanging, tcSymbols.SelectionChanging, myTabControl1.SelectionChanging
    Try
        If Not e.OldSelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            Dim Duration = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500)

            Dim FromOpac As New DoubleAnimation(1, 0, Duration)

            Storyboard.SetTarget(FromOpac, CType(CType(e.OldSelectedItem, DXTabItem).Content, Grid))
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(FromOpac, New PropertyPath((CType(CType(e.OldSelectedItem, DXTabItem).Content, Grid).OpacityProperty)))
            Dim s As New Storyboard()
            s.AccelerationRatio = 0.2
            s.DecelerationRatio = 0.8
            s.Children.Add(FromOpac)

            s.Begin()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub TabControl_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As DevExpress.Xpf.Core.TabControlSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles tcMaterials.SelectionChanged, tcSymbols.SelectionChanged, myTabControl1.SelectionChanged
    Try
        If Not e.OldSelectedItem Is Nothing Then
            Dim Duration = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500)

            Dim ToOpac As New DoubleAnimation(0, 1, Duration)


            Storyboard.SetTarget(ToOpac, CType(CType(e.NewSelectedItem, DXTabItem).Content, Grid))
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ToOpac, New PropertyPath((CType(CType(e.NewSelectedItem, DXTabItem).Content, Grid).OpacityProperty)))
            Dim s As New Storyboard()
            s.AccelerationRatio = 0.2
            s.DecelerationRatio = 0.8
            s.Children.Add(ToOpac)

            s.Begin()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```